# Using one array print frequency of elements in array?

Tags: c

Write an algorithm called occurrences that, given an array of numbers A, prints all the distinct values in A each followed by its number of occurrences.

For example, if `A = <28, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3>`, the algorithm should output the following five lines (here separated by a semicolon `28 1; 1 2; 0 4; 3 2; 4 1`.

The algorithm may modify the content of `A`, but may not use any other memory. 
Each distinct value must be printed exactly once. 
Values may be printed in any order.

Comment: what about this: sort the array and then set a START pointer to location 0 and then move an END pointer along until you find the next new value - the distance is the number of that value.  Then point the START pointer to where the END pointer is and move the END pointer again until you find the next new value - the distance is the number of that next value.

Comment: Nice exercise.  How have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Read from: ["find  frequency of elements in array"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=find+t-frequency-of-elements-in-array&oq=find+t-frequency-of-elements-in-array&aqs=chrome..69i57.2793j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=find++frequency+of+elements+in+array)

Comment: I have solution to this Question. But I can't post it as the Question is put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution will have 2 steps:

1. Sort your array
2. Iterate on array storing current value and number of its occurrences and printing current value/count pair when current value changes

This solution does not require extra memory and has complexity O(n*log(n)) as sorting is the "heaviest" part of algorithm

Comment: Please do not help people with their homework, in particular when they have made no effort as is the case here.

Comment: Well, to by pedantic: for array sorting you need temporary memory locations while you swap values. The howework can't be done, when you read it literally. You will need at least some stack space what violates `but may not use any other memory`. ;-)

Comment: IF they are integers you can swap with XOR using no extra memory.

Comment: @harper, right, probably "constant-size extra memory" would be more appropriate

Comment: exactly, some stack space is needed